# intro. to topology mendelson - closure in a subspace

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I'm self studying intro to topology by Mendelson and I just completed a book problem and wanted to get input on whether it's okay.

The problem statement is,

Let $Y$ be a subspace of $X$ and $A\subset Y$. Prove that $\bar{A}^Y\subset\bar{A}^X$.

Pf:

Let $a\in\bar{A}^Y$ and let $N'$ be any neighborhood of $a$ in $X$. Then $N=N'\cap Y$ is a neighborhood of $a$ in $Y$ with $N\cap A\neq\emptyset$. Thus, we have $N'\cap A=N'\cap Y\cap A=N\cap A\neq\emptyset$. And so $a\in\bar{A}^X$.

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: It looks just fine.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I'm new to this site and so far it has been a extremely helpful. I'll make sure to properly ask questions from now on.

Comment: The proof immediately tells you that if $A$ is a subset of $X$, then $\overline{A\cap Y}^Y\subseteq \overline{A\cap Y}^X\cap Y$. But you may enjoy proving the reverse inclusion, which is also valid. And if furthermore $Y$ is open, then we even have $\overline{A\cap Y}^Y=\overline A^X\cap Y$.

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen this before. I'll try to prove these and see what I get. Thanks for the information.